# Consulta inner join con AND no trae resultados

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla en la cual tengo dos campos: `origen_bodega_id` y `destino_bodega_id`

Tablas involucradas en la query:

- transferencia_bodegas (id,fecha_transferencia,servicio_id) -> obtengo
  la fecha y mediante servicio_id relaciono con la tabla servicios
- servicios (id,servicio) -> de aca obtengo el nombre del servicio
- det_transferencia_bodegas (id, origen_bodega_id, destino_bodega_id,
  cantidad) -> de aca obtengo los bodega_id que se relacionan con la
  tabla bodegas
- bodegas (id,nombre_bodega) ->de aca obtengo el nombre
  de las bodegas

Necesito recuperar el nombre de las bodegas tanto de origen como destino para lo cual estoy usando un inner join`, pero no me esta trayendo la información, solo me trae una bodega y la otra no trae nada...

La consulta que estoy trabajando es esta:

```
select t.fecha_transferencia, t.num_guia_despacho,
s.servicio, b.nombre_bodega
from transferencia_bodegas t
inner join det_transferencia_bodegas d on t.id = d.transferencia_bodega_id
inner join bodegas b on b.id = d.destino_bodega_id 
inner join servicios s on s.id = t.servicio_id
where t.id = d.transferencia_bodega_id
```

Lo que pretendo obtener es algo asi:

| num_guia_despacho | fecha_transferencia | Bodega Origen | Bodega Destino |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2021-03-07 | Bodega A | Bodega B |

Creo que el  AND no esta bien en algo porque si lo quito, me trae al menos el primer nombre de bodega, si lo dejo la consulta no arroja datos.

Saludos

Comment: d.destino_bodega_id = d.destino_bodega_id???? entre el mismo campo?

Comment: Por favor, añade a la pregunta tu dataset (phpmyadmin, exportar) para ver la estructura de la base de datos y hacer alguna prueba con los datos. Recuerda añadir lo que esperas obtener para los datos de prueba que aportes

Comment: @gbianchi hola, era solo una prueba, no trae info

Comment: El query que mostras no tiene nada que ver con la salida que queres... de donde salen esos datos? que tablas estan involucradas? cual es la fuente de datos? asi como esta, parece que queres que adivinemos que es lo que queres obtener.. tene en cuenta que para poder ayudar, necesitamos las cosas claras...

Comment: Vamos mejor... esos 4 campos de que tabla salen? y que tiene que ver el sql que mostras con lo que queres?

Comment: con el sql que edite ahora, obtengo la fecha, el servicio, otro dato y ademas la bodega de destino (destino_bodega_id) pero no logro conseguir tambien la bodega de origen (origen_bodega_id)

Comment: ah ya lo tenes entonces... sabias que podes hacer inner join a la misma tabla mas de una vez ;) le pones otro alias y listo... y joinea por el otro campo ;)

Answer (score 2):

Así como te dijeron en comentarios, tu problema se resuelve realizando un `INNER JOIN` **a la misma tabla mas de una vez, colocando un alias diferente**.

El comando `AS` que añadí es totalmente opcional, siempre va previo a un alias, y es una buena práctica para reconocerlos a simple vista no confundirse con el nombre original de la tabla.

Asimismo, si tu alias consiste en dos palabras separadas, puedes indicarlo colocando corchetes [].

```
SELECT t.num_guia_despacho
    ,t.fecha_transferencia
    ,s.servicio
    ,origen.nombre_bodega AS [Bodega Origen]
    ,destino.nombre_bodega AS [Bodega Destino]
FROM transferencia_bodegas AS t
INNER JOIN det_transferencia_bodegas AS d ON t.id = d.transferencia_bodega_id
INNER JOIN bodegas AS destino ON destino.id = d.destino_bodega_id
INNER JOIN bodegas AS origen ON origen.id = d.origen_bodega_id
INNER JOIN servicios AS s ON s.id = t.servicio_id
WHERE t.id = d.transferencia_bodega_id
```